# How can you redirect folders to files with mod rewrite in linux?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When you go to a website like linkedin, you can  make your own linkedin.com/UserName folder.

How can when a user types website.com/UserName it go to website.com/profile.php?UserName with mod rewrite in .htaccess?

Comment: It's probably done using a mod rewrite. If you want to avoid creating many folders, then that'd be an option.

Comment: I'll check into that. :)

Comment: It is done via Web server configuration - the queries are redirected to some controller (such as PHP script). There are so many ways to implement this, that the answer will not fit the format of SO.

Comment: I'll confine it to mod rewrite then and edit this.  I tried to be as specific as I could.

Comment: Here are a few links that may be of interest (based on linkedin's architecture and a few others) https://www.quora.com/What-is-LinkedIn-s-database-architecture-like --- http://blog.outsourcing-partners.com/2012/10/why-nosql-database-is-used-by-facebook-google-and-linkedin-applications/ --- http://vitalflux.com/data-handled-linkedin-com/ - Yet at this stage, the question would be rather broad.

Comment: Are you looking for https://moz.com/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls ?

Comment: Your suggestions really helped me understand it further.  I see that it can be server/database driven, which is what would be easiest to handle.

Answer (score 1):

For smaller projects you can rely on this type of folder structure but in larger project you've to choose more elegant solution rather than creating thousands of messy folders.

There are already many routing solution available to choose  from. You may have a look on https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router this PHP Router class.